# Redux translating array of objects into hash tree

Tags: redux, react-redux

Here is the code I am working with:

```
const initialState = {
    _requestStatus: null,
    data: {
        domains: {},
    },
};

const transformCustomDomainsData = (state, json) => {
    const { response } = json;
    return {
        domains: {
            ...state.data.domains,
            ...response.map(resp => ({
                id: resp.id,
                domain: resp.domain,
                context: resp.context,
            })),
        },
    };
};
```

I am trying to come up with code that will translate the initial fetch reducer response into a hash tree.

Something like this:

```
const initialState = {
  byHash: {
    '1': {id: '1', content: {title: 'item 1'}},
    '2': {id: '2', content: {title: 'item 2'}},
    '3': {id: '3', content: {title: 'item 3'}}
  }
}
```

Where the key in the `byHash` is the id of each item in the array and the value is each object in the json response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

```
const transformCustomDomainsData = (state, json) => {
    const { response } = json;
    return {
        domains: {
            ...state.data.domains,
            ...response.reduce((obj, resp) => {
                obj[resp.id] = resp;
                return obj;
            }, {}),
        },
    };
};
```